# What is the difference between != and <> in python?

Tags: python

Why do we have two two not equals sign in python.
 Is there any difference? 
 Or is there any difference in memory allocation?

Comment: `<>` is deprecated in Py3, Use `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL` to get it back.

Comment: They are different spellings for the same operator. Usually we use `!=`. `<>` is obsolescent (as stated in the python docs).

Comment: They're the same, but `<>` is the old operator. Use `!=`

Comment: The forms `<>` and `!=` are equivalent; but `!=` is preferred. Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/comparisons.html)